# Using the word "sad" after a noun

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, usage, ambiguity

On Collins dictionary, one of the meanings of "sad" is: "**If you describe someone as sad, you do not have any respect for them and think their behavior or ideas are ridiculous.**", and it says that it is usually used before nouns in this meaning. So since it says it is usually used before nouns, is it wrong if I say like **"Man... You people are sad."** to some people for meaning that I despise them? Does it mean that I find them saddening instead? I think what I mean can be understood from the context. Am I right? Also, do you agree with that it is usually used before nouns instead of after nouns in this meaning?

You can see the Collins Dictionary definitions here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sad The one I am referring to is the forth definition.

Comment: In **you people are sad,** **sad** comes after a *verb* not a *noun* . . . (At least directly. You might want to be more specific in your question.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford In dictionaries, sentences like "He is good" and "He is sad" are shown as [NOUN adjective], and sentences like "He is a good man" and "He is a sad man" are shown as [ADJECTIVE noun].

Comment: That's true, and I didn't say anything different . . .

Comment: @Jason Bassford Thanks. And, can I say the sentence I gave in my post for meaning that I despise them?

Comment: It *can* be used as a slang expression. It depends on the context. (It can also be used to mean exactly what *sad people* means.) It is, however, still an adjectival phrase, and not an adverb. Also, I would not interpret the slang *sad* to mean "despised"; instead, I would say it means "pitiable."

Comment: "You people are sad" says more about the person uttering it. It is used as an insult from the speaker's perspective, even more insulting due to the use of "you people". Suppose I say "the people are happy" or "the people are sad", these are my observations about how they feel, not the value judgement contained in the insult.

Answer (score -1):

Your interest in the usage of "***Sad***" is very topical as it has been commandeered since it's one of Donald Trump's favorites to use in the Twittersphere.

[image]

[image]

If you wanted to say *someone* was *saddening*, you might say

> You are **depressing**.

or

> The situation is **heartbreaking**.

Comment: Thanks. So, then it can quite often be used after nouns too. By the way, I am living in a dictatorship and imgur is banned here. So, I can't reach those links.

Comment: No. Please go back and read Jason Bradford's comment. Adjectives precede the noun modified unless you have a noun verb adjective form. Furthermore, the use of "sad" in the sense that you are discussing is highly colloquial in the US  and, in that particular sense, has little to do with the word "saddening."

Comment: @FireandIce it’s about the pattern, not the actual text. Trump’s pattern is “<Some statement, possibly unfounded.> Sad!”